# Convert CIM_DATETIME in Bash/Python

Tags: python, bash, timestamp

I have a `CIM_DATETIME` time acquired from `wmic os get lastbootuptime`:

```
20190309221835.234400-480
```

`CIM_DATETIME` is formatted as follows:

```
yyyymmddHHMMSS.mmmmmmsUUU
```

How can I convert that to something more human-friendly in Bash or Python?

Format that would be most desierable is:

```
Sunday, March 10th, 2019 @ 16:01:30 UTC
```

That or if I could convert it to something normal like a Unix timestamp. If you're wondering my need for this in non-Windows languages (there are already many solutions in Batch) is because I do computer forensics but I run Linux as my main OS so I want to be able to easily interpret dates I get from WMI into something I can interpret easily. It's so niche I'm unable to even find a tool online to do it. :/

Thank you.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Done deal!

Comment: It would have been nice if the desired output corresponded to the given input.

Comment: @Armali Good point! Timezones and converting formats gets confusing real fast. Got to have something to error check by.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the timestamp without the timezone with this:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(CIM_DATETIME.split('-')[0], '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f')
```

[Notice, that assumes a negative timezone offset to split the string.]
The catch with the timezone is it is expressed in minutes so you have to divide by 60. But do you need to read the timezone? If it will always be the same then you will be able to bring that in separately.

Comment: Thanks, but for computer forensics the timezone really is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

> but for computer forensics the timezone really is preferable.

combinatorist's answer already does half of the work. It can easily be expanded to take the time zone offset into account:

```
import datetime
CIM_DATETIME ='20190309221835.234400-480'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(CIM_DATETIME[:-4], '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f')
# dt is now datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 9, 22, 18, 35, 234400)
dt -= datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(CIM_DATETIME[-4:]))
# dt is now datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 10, 6, 18, 35, 234400)
dt.strftime("%A, %B %d., %Y @ %X UTC")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution in Bash i came up with. The output seems to be correct and align with the time a couple of days ago I booted up the Windows box -- just before midnight. I also removed the "@" because it barely made the time nicer to look at and made it so I had to remove it in following scripts using `CIM_DATETIME` due to the `date` command not being able to parse that.

```
CIM_DATETIME="20190309221835.234400-480"

date="${CIM_DATETIME:0:8}"
date="$(date -d "$date" '+%A, %B%e, %Y')"

time="${CIM_DATETIME:8:6}"
time="$(echo "$time" | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//')" # Adds : between hours, minutes and seconds of time so it can be parsed correctly

timezone="${CIM_DATETIME:21}"
time="$time $timezone"

time="$(date -d "$time" '+%r %Z')"

echo "$date $time"
```

Example Output: `Saturday, March 9, 2019 11:38:35 PM EDT`

Thank you for all the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my improved version of Armali's answer that deals with negative / null / positive timezones, and allows to use UTC or local notation:

[EDIT]
Disclaimer: The code in this post is outdated.
**I have published that code as a python package.**
Install with `pip install windows_tools.installed_software`

Usage:

```
from windows_tools.wmi_queries import cim_timestamp_to_datetime_utc

print(cim_timestamp_to_datetime_utc('20201103225935.123456+0'))
```

[/EDIT]

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re

def convert_cim_timestamp(cim_timestamp: str, utc_result: bool = True) -> str:
    """
    Convert WMI timestamp to python datetime object
    """
    cim_time, cim_tz = re.split('[+-]', cim_timestamp)
    dt = datetime.strptime(cim_time, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f')
    if not utc_result:
        dt -= timedelta(minutes=int(cim_tz))
        return dt.strftime('%A, %B %d., %Y @ %X')
    else:
        utc_sign = '+' if '+' in cim_timestamp else '-'
        utc_offset = int(int(cim_tz)/60)
        return dt.strftime("%A, %B %d., %Y @ %X UTC{}{}".format(utc_sign, utc_offset))


# Example
cim_tz = '20201103225935.123456-240'
print(convert_cim_timestamp(cim_tz))
cim_tz = '20201103225935.123456+120'
print(convert_cim_timestamp(cim_tz))
```

Comment: seems to me like it would be easier to set the timedelta as a timezone (replace tzinfo) and then (if desired output is string) use `%z` in formatting directive. furthermore, kwarg `utc_result` is kind of misleading; the output then has a UTC offset specified, it isn't *converted* to UTC.

Comment: Thanks, as suggested in the edit, this is old code, and has been changed in the git repo ;)